# Converting image datatype to varbinary(max) on dtproperties table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've just converted all the columns with datatypes of `text` and `image` to `varchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` respectively. However, I still have the `dtproperties` system table with the lvalue column that is of type image. Is there going to be any problem changing the datatype for this system table? The database has been around quite awhile, obviously.

Using SQL Server 2008, SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, can anyone comment on whether it would be better to do an ALTER statement or just change it from the design function?

Are there any scripts to identify all tables and columns that need to be changed and then execute that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and found out that dtproperties is a table associated with database diagrams created in SQL Server Management Studio.  That alleviated my fears, so I went ahead and changed the datatype.

I did need to use an ALTER statement, since it was a system table.  I was unable to change it in the design mode.

Comment: you can also drop the table, it gets recreated by SQL Studio if needed. (unless of course you use the diagrams before).

Answer (score 0):

Ex.

```
SELECT CAST( 123456 AS BINARY(4) )

SET @BinaryVariable2 = 123456
SET @BinaryVariable2 = @BinaryVariable2 + 1

SELECT CAST( @BinaryVariable2 AS INT)
GO
```

The final result is 57921, not 123457.

Comment: Is that relevant for the question about IMAGE? I think not.